Data exists on data table but return 404
I'm new to Prisma and SQL. I encounter a problem while working on a booking app project.
Problem Description:
In a Next.js 14.2 application using App Router, I'm encountering a 404 error when trying to fetch data for a specific reservation. The error occurs in a server component that's attempting to fetch data from an API route.
Key Details:
1. Environment: Next.js 14.2 with App Router, Prisma ORM, and NextAuth for authentication.
2. Component Location: `app/reservation/[reservationId]/page.tsx`
3. API Route Location: `app/api/reservations/[reservationId]/route.ts`
4. Error Message:
Error fetching reservation: Error: Failed to fetch reservation
    at fetchReservation (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/reservation/[reservationId]/page.tsx:25:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)
    at async RecentReservation (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/reservation/[reservationId]/page.tsx:33:23)
 GET /api/reservations/cm26oj3710008wlt4zwex8o9w 404 in 32ms

Relevant Code:
/app/reservation/[reservationId]/page.tsx
import Link from 'next/link'
import { Card, CardContent, CardHeader, CardTitle } from "@/components/ui/card"
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"
import { CalendarDays, Clock, User, Scissors } from 'lucide-react'

interface Reservation {
  id: string
  date: string
  time: string
  stylist: string
  service: string
}

async function fetchReservation(reservationId: string): Promise<Reservation> {
  const baseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL || 'http://localhost:3000';
  console.log('baseUrl', baseUrl)
  const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/api/reservation/${reservationId}`, { cache: 'no-store' })

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch reservation')
  }

  return res.json()
}

export default async function RecentReservation({ params }: { params: { reservationId: string } }) {
  let reservation: Reservation | null = null
  let error: string | null = null

  try {
    reservation = await fetchReservation(params.reservationId)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error fetching reservation:', err)
    error = 'Failed to load reservation. Please try again.'
  }

  if (error) {
    return (
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-screen">
        <p className="text-red-500 mb-4">{error}</p>
        <Link href="/" passHref>
          <Button className="bg-rose-500 hover:bg-rose-600">
            Back to Home
          </Button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    )
  }

  if (!reservation) {
    return (
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-screen">
        <p className="text-red-500 mb-4">Reservation not found. Please contact us for assistance.</p>
        <Link href="/" passHref>
          <Button className="bg-rose-500 hover:bg-rose-600">
            Back to Home
          </Button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto px-4 py-12">
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold mb-8 text-center">Your Recent Reservation</h1>
      <Card className="max-w-2xl mx-auto">
        <CardHeader>
          <CardTitle>Reservation Details</CardTitle>
        </CardHeader>
        <CardContent className="space-y-4">
          <div className="flex items-center">
            <CalendarDays className="mr-2 h-5 w-5 text-rose-500" />
            <span>Date: {new Date(reservation.date).toLocaleDateString()}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex items-center">
            <Clock className="mr-2 h-5 w-5 text-rose-500" />
            <span>Time: {reservation.time}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex items-center">
            <User className="mr-2 h-5 w-5 text-rose-500" />
            <span>Stylist: {reservation.stylist}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex items-center">
            <Scissors className="mr-2 h-5 w-5 text-rose-500" />
            <span>Service: {reservation.service}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-center mt-6">
            <Link href="/" passHref>
              <Button className="bg-rose-500 hover:bg-rose-600">
                Back to Home
              </Button>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </div>
  )
}

/app/api/reservations/route.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"
import { authOptions } from '../../../../libs/auth/authOptions'
import prisma from '../../../../libs/prisma'


export async function GET(
  req: NextRequest,
  { params }: { params: { reservationId: string } }
) {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)

  if (!session || !session.user) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Unauthorized' }, { status: 401 })
  }

  try {
    const reservation = await prisma.reservation.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: params.reservationId,
      },
    })

    if (!reservation) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Reservation not found' }, { status: 404 })
    }

    if (reservation.userId !== session.user.id) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Unauthorized' }, { status: 403 })
    }

    return NextResponse.json(reservation)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Fetch reservation error:', error)
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Failed to fetch reservation' }, { status: 500 })
  }
}

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)

  if (!session || !session.user) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Unauthorized' }, { status: 401 })
  }

  try {
    const { date, time, stylist, service } = await req.json()

    if (!date || !time || !stylist || !service) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Missing required fields' }, { status: 400 })
    }

    const reservation = await prisma.reservation.create({
      data: {
        date: new Date(date),
        time,
        stylist,
        service,
        userId: session.user.id,
      },
    })

    return NextResponse.json(reservation, { status: 201 })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Reservation creation error:', error)
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Failed to create reservation' }, { status: 500 })
  }
}



I try to query on Vercel Postgres and found it. The data exists on Prisma Studio as well.

Your route handler path is incorrect. It should be /app/api/reservations/[reservationId]/route.ts

Omg what a dull mistake. Thank you so much Phil. You made my day
